# Setting public read for cloud storage object via Golang in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to set public permissions to a google cloud storage object that I have uploaded.

The upload happens via a go application that runs on Google App Engine, using the `google.golang.org/api/storage/v1` package.

From the same code, I am able to create and delete any object, however trying to set public read fails with the following error:

`googleapi: Error 403: Insufficient Permission, insufficientPermissions`

This is my code:

```
if _, err := service.ObjectAccessControls.Update(bucketNameDone, object, "allUsers", &storage.ObjectAccessControl{Role: "READER", Object: object}).Do(); err != nil {
    log.Errorf(ctx, "failed to set public perms for %s: %v", object, err)
}
```

The docs for this suck pretty badly so I can't figure out what I am missing. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to create http client  with sufficient permission to do stuff on the bucket .
Ill will send you example later  need to run to the bus :)
storageService, err := storage.New(oauthHttpClient)

Comment: @MIkCode thanks, looking forward. Please note two things: 1. I am able to delete objects and buckets with the same permissions, so I don't think it's a simple perms issue - more likely something in the way I am trying to update the ACL 2. I have to run this on GAE, which has some special limitations

Comment: did you set the scope to storage.ScopeFullControl ?

Comment: there appears to be no such scope in the storage package above mentioned: "undefined: storage.ScopeFullControl". I'm using "scope.DevstorageFullControlScope" - which allows me to create/delete buckets and objects so I don't think that's the issue

Comment: meanwhile my workaround was to create a designated bucket for this action, and on that bucket I set default ACL to public read as explained here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/defacl